# I use Nuxtjs, I do not have access to the filterText data variable

Tags: nuxt.js

I use vue-isotope inside Nuxtjs, I do not have access to the filterText data variable, can someone help me ?

```
data: () => ({
  filterText: null,
  option: {
    getFilterData: {
      filterByText: function(itemElem) {
        console.log(this.filterText) // undefined
      }
    }
  }
}
```

complete code
https://jsfiddle.net/johanrm/h2ekjcy4/2

Comment: you cannot access it. why don't you use computed property to do that

Comment: I am a beginner in vuejs and nuxt js, I do not have too many ideas but thank you for the advice I will study this

Comment: I follow the advice of this code the https://jsfiddle.net/dede89/g6c0vzm2/

Comment: flat on its version it works, access to 'this.filterText' is possible

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to preserve the `this` context of `data` function. You have to pass the same `this` context to the `filterByText` function.

`Normal function` has its own `this` context so if you use `normal function` you cannot access the objects in the outer context using `this`.

`shorthand function` or `arrow function` doesnot have its own `this` context. `this` context wouldn't get overridden in this case, so you need to use `arrow function` to access the parent's `this` context.

Try below code and see if it solves your problem

```
data() {
    return{
      filterText: "im filter",
      option: {
        getFilterData: {
          filterByText: (itemElem) =>{
            console.log(this.filterText) // im filter
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is a concept of `javascript` and its not related to `vue` or `nuxt`
[This article](https://javascript.info/arrow-functions) will give you an idea on what `arrow function` is about